# Facing Issue in VS Code

Tags: java, arrays, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-java

Visual Studio Code
Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. Reason: Failed to launch debuggee in terminal.

Reason: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: timeout
Open 'launch.json' Cancel

pop up gives this error and then opened up launch.json file

I have tried to edit launch.json file as here someone suggested but nothing happens.

Go through multiple youtube videos and not getting any kind of similar error

Answer (score 0):

Delete *launch.json* and create a new one and use the original *launch.json*. also make sure you have used the latest version of vscode and java extensions or use the java extensions pre-release version.

[image]

Also try to add the following setting in the ***settings.json***.

```json
    "java.debug.settings.forceBuildBeforeLaunch": false,
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Edit your question to add more description of the problem, e.g. what action did you perform to get the error?Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)